# How to make a Mask in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, paint, mask

I have a duvifa that is:

I wonder if it is possible to make a mask in a movieClip the way it is below:

If this image would be the beginning of the game.

[image]

When the user clicks on the screen, a type of cream would be created, but not like he would extend all over the stage, but only in my way.

[image]

As below:

[image]

And also like to know if I can get a percentage of what was filled in the form, to see if the user has filled at least 40%.

Thank U.

Comment: The mask is easy enough, you can either clone the background image and use it as the mask of the cream, or use `ALPHA` blend mode on it and set the common parent's blend mode to `LAYER`.     The 40% thing would probably involve reading pixel data, a little more complicated.

Comment: I Got You! Thank you, but would you make a example AS3 code of how to do this? I am new to ActionScript.

Comment: Show your current code and then an example can be tailored to that

Comment: That's the problem .. I do not have a game start yet, so I wanted to ask you if you can make an example with simple images, such as up to my study. hugs

Comment: Are you using flashPro, or some thing else like flash builder or flash develop?

Comment: Friend, I'm using Adobe Flash CS6 ... if only pure ActionScript ... Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example using flashPro, assuming you have your shape graphic as an import .png library object with an export for actionscript class of `MC`.

```
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.BlendMode;

var mc:MC = new MC(); //the background image
addChild(mc);

var drawing:Shape = new Shape();  //drawing foreground
addChild(drawing);

var mcMask:MC = new MC(); //mask version of background image
addChild(mcMask);

var outerMask:Shape = new Shape(); //this object masks the areas outside the bounds of mcMask object
outerMask.graphics.beginFill(0);
outerMask.graphics.drawRect(0,0,mcMask.width,mcMask.height);
outerMask.graphics.endFill();
addChild(outerMask);

drawing.mask = outerMask; //the mask to the shape whose dimensions equal the image mask

mcMask.blendMode = BlendMode.ALPHA; //this tells the mask graphic to make things underneath it use the same alpha data as this image.  This works will with PNG masks.
this.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER; //the parent needs to have a blend mode of LAYER for it to work properly

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,draw);

function draw(e:Event):void {
    trace("draw");
    drawing.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
    drawing.graphics.drawCircle(mouseX,mouseY,10);
    drawing.graphics.endFill();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Gave an adapted the code, but it worked perfectly ... now only missing part of reading the pixels ... if you have any idea how to do this, please help me ...

Comment: I've done it before, but that was probably 8 years ago.  I'll see if i can dig up that old project

Comment: Thank you for your help and attention! Posted this question in a new section, if you want to meet there ... Hugs! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164098/retrieving-percentage-of-colors-of-a-movieclip